# App shows "push" as title in android overview screen when opened from push notification?

Tags: android

The app title is shows as "push" in the apps overview screen in android when my app is opened from a push notification.

But when opened from the launcher screen it shows proper title. How to set the title for the app in overview screen when opening the app from push notification?

Comment: What is you app label in manifest file application tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this via ActivityManager.TaskDescription:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription.html

From an Activity context, call:

TaskDescription taskDescription = new TaskDescription(label, icon, colorPrimary);
((Activity)this).setTaskDescription(taskDescription);

To clarify more: * Label - text on the card header * Icon - left bitmap icon (usually an icon which looks good on the 'colorPrimary' color * colorPrimary - the card header color (usually same as the Toolbar color, but not necessarily) This solution worked for me

Comment: Should I set for every activity? I just need one global title, icon for the whole app.

Comment: The ActionBar title displayed at the top of the screen is governed by the AndroidManifest.xml file within the activity nodes. In the example below, the activity "FirstActivity" will have an ActionBar with the string value of the resource identified by @string/activity_name. If the value of that resource is "Foo," the string displayed in the ActionBar for this activity will be "Foo." Note that the application node can supply a android:label that acts as the default for activities and components with no other specified label.

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.codepath.example.simpleapp.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_name" >
        </activity>
</application>